# Получить данные из массива в другой массив

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4208
            [1] => 666
            [2] => 110004208
            [3] => 110004208
            [4] => 515511
            [5] => 515511
            [6] => 428 Fastback
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4209
            [1] => 666
            [2] => 110004209
            [3] => 110004209
            [4] => 515515
            [5] => 515515
            [6] => 428 кабрио
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4210
            [1] => 666
            [2] => 110004210
            [3] => 110004210
            [4] => 534924
            [5] => 534924
            [6] => ACE
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4211
            [1] => 666
            [2] => 110004211
            [3] => 110004211
            [4] => 534924
            [5] => 534924
            [6] => ACE
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4212
            [1] => 666
            [2] => 110004212
            [3] => 110004212
            [4] => 534925
            [5] => 534925
            [6] => ACECA
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4213
            [1] => 666
            [2] => 110004213
            [3] => 110004213
            [4] => 534926
            [5] => 534926
            [6] => COBRA Mk IV (291N)
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4207
            [1] => 666
            [2] => 110004207
            [3] => 110004207
            [4] => 515510
            [5] => 515510
            [6] => ME
        )

)
```

Как мне из него получить данныt в другой массив $a. при этом мне нужны лишь данные с индексами 5 и 6 из первого массива

```
[5] => 515511
[6] => 428 Fastback

[5] => 515515
[6] => 428 кабрио

И т.д.
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Любые операции с массивами производятся с помощью циклов.

- Оператор перебора массивов `foreach` является одной из базовых конструкций языка, его не знать невозможно.
- Оператор добавления данных в новый массив `[]` также должен быть известен.

То есть, вопрос опять не "как сделать", а "почему у меня не работает". (Как стало видно из комментариев автора - проблема не в этом коде, а в том, как его использовать в связке с предыдущим).

Update. Хотел сразу написать, но засомневался - обычно начинающие работают с ассоциативными индексами при получении из базы, а тут цифры. То есть больше похоже на джейсон и осмысленную задачу. Ан нет, это всё-таки работа с БД и мартышкин труд по переливанию из пустого в порожнее.

Если данные приходят из БД, то **надо сразу запрашивать только те два поля, которые нужны.**

То есть, если делать по-человечески, а не классик похапе-стайл, то

```
$a = $pdo->query("SELECT field5, field6 FROM table")->fetchAll();
```

без колупания с mysql_fetch_row, без переливания из массива в массив, без вот этого вот всего.

PS. И все-таки удивительно, кто ему доверил рулить базой на 6М записей. Его же даже SO-driven development не спасает.

Answer (score 1):

Пример с упомянутым перебором в цикле:

```
$in_arr = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77],
    [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777]
];
$out_arr = [];

foreach ($in_arr as $v) {
    $out_arr[] = [$v[5], $v[6]];
}
```

$out_arr:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    [0] => int(6)
    [1] => int(7)
  }
  [1] => array(2) {
    [0] => int(66)
    [1] => int(77)
  }
  [2] => array(2) {
    [0] => int(666)
    [1] => int(777)
  }
}
```

Comment: Пока писал сообщение - ты меня опередил))) +1 тебе)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = [/* исходный массив с данными */];
$a = []; // Определяем новый массив

foreach($array as $key => $value) $a[] = [$value[5], $value[6]]; // заполняем данными

print_r($a); // выводим результат

?>
```

Попробуй так)

Comment: while ($r =  mysql_fetch_row($q)) $b[] = $r;
foreach ($b as $value) {
$a = array($value[5], $value[6]);
} Не работает

Comment: И не будет, если Вы не поставите `$a[] = array($value[5], $value[6]);`. Массив не заполняется, а присваевается.